# docker container created with docker composer is failing to access yum repository although the Vm can access

Tags: linux, docker

i have logged onto the container console and set http_proxy, https_proxy and no_proxy with export command
I have put the IP address of the proxy.

```
export http_proxy=http://10.177.38.133:80
export https_proxy=http://10.177.38.133:80
export no_proxy="*.xxxx.com,*.xxxxx.com"
```

i am doing

```
yum install pip3
```

the command fails to  execute and loops on as below

```
yum install pip3
Loaded plugins: ovl, ulninfo
https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/UEKR4/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/UEKR4/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
```

on ping is see that ping does not come back from proxy 
although VM is working fine; on VM I am able to ping the proxy, yum works as expected.
Please help

Comment: I don't think that's not how you enable proxy for yum.

Comment: might be some certificates issue? that you have in your VM but not within the container?